# get user rank (mySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm making a login, with ranks. When you are logged In you receive a welcome message. But that's diffrent for every rank. 
my index.php:

```
<?php 
    include_once("config.php");
?>

<?php if( !(isset( $_POST['login'] ) ) ) { ?>

<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
        echo "Welcome ";    
        if ($rank == 1) {
            echo "default user";
        }
        if ($rank == 10) {
            echo "developer! right?";
        }
        else {
            echo "error";
        }

    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
    }
}
?>
```

but how do I get the user ranks?
my sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` varbinary(250) NOT NULL,
  `rank` varbinary(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`,`username`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=8 ;
```

how do I edit my code so I can get the rank of user?

Thanks!

**EDIT AFTER Zsolt Szilagy's ANSWER:**

```
 $rank = 'SELECT rank FROM users WHERE userID = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($usr->get_userID()) . '"';
```

^^doesn't works^^ or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Euhm "How do I get the user ranks?" Did you try a select query?

Comment: What does your Users class look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'SELECT rank FROM users WHERE userID = "' . mysql_real_escape_string($usr->get_userID()) . '"';
```

Depending on your getters, on how the object was loaded, and on your db abstraction.

Comment: Of course it doesn´t, we cannot no your framework, or what getters you have. This is an approach that shall point you the direction, unless you can provide more context. :) (Please always provide more information than "error" if you expect any usefull help.)

Comment: the "error" leaded to a screenshot with the error, but here it is briefly than:                                                       Fatal error: Call to undefined method Users::get_userID() in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\index.php on

Comment: Sure thing, you don´t have a getter named get_userID(). Note the "Depending on your getters" part of the answer.